# Firefox performance Google Maps

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-maps

I am developing a google mapi api implementation (v3), but I mainly use Firefox 12 for developing because of Firebug. I think Firebug is a great tool, much better than the one in Chrome.

But compared to Chrome Firefox is SO slow with loading, scrolling etc! I doesn't even want to do continuous scrolling..

Is there a way to improve Firefox' performance on Google maps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Easy Solution**

Ironically, it is probably Firebug which is slowing down Google Maps for you so much.  To increase performance, the easiest thing would be to disable Firebug when you're not doing development.

**Better Solution**

Unfortunately, often times disabling such a useful tool is not an acceptable solution.  Thankfully it's only a few components of Firebug that play the biggest role in slowing things down.  The biggest performance gains come from disabling the "console" and/or "net" tabs, either by clicking them and deselecting enabled, or going through the options tab.  Firebug's performance hit is most noticeable on Google Maps because of the large amount of requests it makes and the complex DOM structure.

**Backup Plan**

If that doesn't help, you can try updating Firefox and Firebug and hope that they've improved performance in recent versions.  The most recent version as of when I am writing this is Firebug 1.10.0a7 for Firefox 12, and on my machine it seems to perform reasonably well even with net and console enabled.

Comment: I am using firebug 1.11.1 and cannot seem to find the option to disable firebug for the maps.google.com url and/or gmail.com url. I have found some resources online who say that it will be hidden in a dropdown arrow near the 'net' tab on the firebug panel. but that menu does not show. disable firebug for domain x

Comment: Firebug should by default remember on which URLs you have it enabled and disabled, following the same origin policy.  Take a look at http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Activation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, I found that disabling the "use hardware acceleration when available" option made google maps *really* a lot more responsive

Find it in Preferences -> Advanced -> General -> Browsing

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all Google cookies solves this issue for me - Google Maps scroll and zoom become super-smooth.  However, the lag consistently reappears after re-logging in and a minute or two of usage.  Maybe that's enough information for someone else to run further with the issue.

My current workaround is to open Google Maps queries (through Alfred) in a private window, so no cookies are present:

`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --private-window http://maps.google.com/maps?q={query}`

Unfortunately the private window can't have my account info so I don't have access to saved places.

Background: I noticed that Maps was way smoother in a Private Firefox window than a normal window.  Disabling all add-ons didn't make a difference.  I cleared all cookies to try and make the Normal FF window as similar as possible to the Private window.  After that everything immediately became lag-free.

Unfortunately I have no idea what particular cookie(s) cause the slowdown.

Answer (score -2):

Consider using [maps.bing.com](http://maps.bing.com): I'm not sure what it is about google maps that makes firefox slow, but it's not just a browser issue; bing maps doesn't have the issue.  (indeed, chrome seems to exhibit oddly unsharp tiles when scrolling on bing maps, in a  fashion reminiscent of firefox's [quirks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/928702) on google maps).

I hope firefox finds a solution, because I'm not holding my breath for google to.

Comment: Using another map service doesn't solve the author's problem with Google's map service.

Comment: If your aim is specifically to use google's mapping site, then sure - but if your aim is merely to have a fast, responsive mapping service, then I beg to differ.  Incidentally; google maps has been refreshed since I last posted this, and unfortunately, the new maps is even slower on firefox.